# Define a simple string JNDI property in Weblogic 10.0

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

My application requires a JNDI property, which basically is a simple java.lang.String.
In tomcat this is easy to define the context.xml, while it's also easy in the glassfish admin console.

However, I cannot find how to do this in Weblogic 10.0.
My property should be in java:comp/env

*EDIT*

I have found another question, where answers show this isn't really possible out of the box in WLS 10.0
[Adding custom object to JNDI on Weblogic 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042775/adding-custom-object-to-jndi-on-weblogic-10)

However, there is a plugin which would do the trick:
http://code.google.com/p/weblogic-jndi-startup/

I changed my code to fall back on an environment veriable if this fails. Not too nice, but fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/configureresources.html#wp159026

I think it might at least give you a direction. Setting a value to the property seems to be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

try the [weblogic-jndi-startup](https://code.google.com/p/weblogic-jndi-startup/)

> Unlike JBoss and Glassfish there is no way to define a custom JNDI
>   object (eg a URL) in the WebLogic console. This provides a very simple
>   way to do that.

in your case, you can use the String object instead of the URL one

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
String url = String.valueOf(context.lookup("configURL"));
```